# Recovering ext4 superblock

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4

I had an ext4 filesystem in an LV which got destroyed because I accidentally shrunk the partition it was in way too small. After expanding the partition back to the original size, I put a new ext4 FS on the LV because in its current state `udev` wouldn't even give it a device file.

I need to recover the older superblock which I'm hoping still has a good backup somewhere.

How do I find it? Can I?

`testdisk` seems to find a bunch of them but none of them work.

Comment: If the files are small and continuous on the disk and have a detectable header, it could be easier to recover the files from the raw data (using e.g. [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/)) instead of recovering the whole file system.

Comment: @jofel I have already retrieved a decent amount with foremost but there are some things like game saves and my dogecoin wallet that I have been less successful in recovering.

Answer (score 5):

You may be in luck, and have backup superblocks on the partition.  If you can remember the options used to create the filesystem (e.g. you just used defaults), then you can find the locations of the backups like so:

```
sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -n <original_options> <device>
```

The `-n` is critically important - it is a "dry-run" option that won't write anything to the disk (it's probably still a good idea to dump the disk to a safe place whilst you're experimenting - I'll assume you've already done so).

Even if you can't remember the original options, the above is worth trying, to get a candidate list.

Now, for each candidate superblock, try mounting with `-o ro,sb=<n>` to use the alternate superblock (and read-only).  If successful, you may be able to recover some files.

If none of the candidate superblocks allows a successful mount, a last-ditch effort may be to write a new superblock using the `-S` option to `mkfs.ext4`: "*Write  superblock  and  group descriptors only.  This is useful if all of the superblock and backup superblocks are corrupted, and a last-ditch recovery method is desired.*"  I would *not* do this without a full partition backup somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure the disk is read-only, so that no more writes happen to it while trying to recover the data.

The ext4 superblock is hard to find, because the contents vary a lot, depending on the inode count, block count etc. However, there is a magic signature 0xEF53 (16 bits) that you can try to search for. If you can find the right place, then the start of the superblock (and also the total inode count) should be placed 56 bytes (0x38 bytes in hex) before that.

It is likely that you will find many instances of 0xEF53, but by checking for other likely values in the superblock, you might be able to identify it.

Here is the table of ext4 superblock values: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block

Using a hex editor for the entire disk image might yield results.

Writing a program (or pay someone to do it) that searches through data for something that looks like an ext4 superblock might also be an idea. (For instance, the 32-bit number at offset 72 (0x48) should be 0, since the OS is "Linux").

Best of luck.

Comment: After I find the offset how do I check to see if it's a valid ext4 superblock?

Comment: That's the trick, you need to check that enough values are correct according to the ext4 superblock table, to convince you that it might be the correct location and size.

Comment: So for the total inode count 0x0 does that extend from 0x0-0x3? Since the next entry is 0x4?

Comment: Yes, bytes 0, 1, 2 and 3 are part of the 8+8+8+8 = 32-bit number (written as "__le32" in the table).

[ghex](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Ghex) might be helpful, but I would recommend using a program or script instead, if possible, to avoid having to search manually.