# Interpreting dd Input/Output error

Tags: linux, dd

I tried to copy `/dev/Storage/Storage` (an LV under LVM) to an image file
using a `dd | pv | dd` pipeline. `dd` reported an error, and I want to know
whether `dd` finished copying my disk or stopped due to the error.
I'm not sure since it gave me two different outputs:
one with an error at the top and one without.
I'd take a guess and say it didn't because between the two there's only an extra 0.1 seconds and no extra data, but I'm not sure if it did or not.
`/dev/Storage/Storage` is
a 1 TB disk (terabyte = 10<sup>12</sup> = 1000<sup>4</sup>)
or 931.51 GiB (gibibyte = 2<sup>30</sup> = 1024<sup>3</sup>)
or 1953513472 sectors.
The filesystem on the disk is messed up and doesn't work properly.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/Storage/Storage | pv | dd of=Storage.img
dd: error reading ‘/dev/Storage/Storage’: Input/output error                   ]
1627672400+0 records ins] [   <=>                                              ]
1627672400+0 records out
833368268800 bytes (833 GB) copied, 75181 s, 11.1 MB/s
776GB 20:53:01 [10.6MB/s] [  <=>                                              ]
1627672400+0 records in
1627672400+0 records out
833368268800 bytes (833 GB) copied, 75181.1 s, 11.1 MB/s
```

Comment: (1) Please show the command(s) that you typed to get this output.  (2) Do you know how big you disk is?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to provide the requested information.

Comment: One obvious question is whether your disk has 1627672400 sectors or not.  Try `blockdev --getsz /dev/whatever`.  If you copied the right number of sectors, then you are probably okay.

Comment: @user3188445 taking that as a no it didn't finish because it's 1953513472 sectors.

Comment: @Scott I updated my question but it's looking like it didn't finish...which means another 20+ hour copy.

Comment: Rather than using `dd` for this you might want to take a look at `ddrescue`. There are actually 2 programs by that name: 1) the original, which is normally named `dd_rescue`, and 2) a GNU program with the package name `gddrescue. The GNU program is generally better & far easier to use than the original one, although IIRC the original has a few extra features that are sometimes useful.

Comment: (cont) `ddrescue` has several advantages over `dd` for recovery work, especially from faulty hardware. It doesn't stop for mere read errors, and because `ddrescue` records its progress to a logfile, if it's interrupted for any reason it can resume recovery. If necessary, it can make multiple passes over a device to try to recover as much data as possible from a dying disk. The basic operation is similar to `dd` but I strongly advise reading the docs thoroughly before you attempt to use it.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes I'm familiar with `ddrescue` I chose `dd` because I don't need the functionality of `ddrescue`. The FS on the disk is a mess but that's due to a partitioning mistake on my part. The disk itself is completely fine. In fact the reason it read errored is because during the copy there was another accident on the disk while using some other software to work on it while dd was copying it and I think that's what caused it. The second time around it worked like a charm.

Comment: Ah, ok. I mostly mentioned `ddrescue` for its resumability, after reading your comment complaining about another 20+ hour copy. You _can_ resume with `dd`, but you have to be very careful not to mess up the offset calculations or the image file will be rubbish. I'm glad you were able to recover successfully. Having a scrambled disk can be very unpleasant.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yea well now it's just a matter of fixing the FS on the disk. Although I don't know I'll be very successful with that. No one has responded to my question on here regarding ext4 superblock searching and restoring. I got some of my data back thanks to foremost but it's a mess to search through and I'm still missing some.

Comment: Any luck with [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)?

Comment: @PM2Ring No. It found a bunch of ext4 filesystems but every time I opened them it would tell me there were no files found or it couldn't open it. So I have to find some other way.

Comment: @PM2Ring If you want to know my situation http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/223428/101019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You are using the default 512 bytes `dd` block size. You would significantly improve performance by using a larger block size, say `128k` or even `1m`.
- There are two outputs because you are running two `dd` commands, the first one is the device reader and it shows an I/O error.
- You are likely using LVM given the device name you use: `/dev/Storage/Storage`. Are you sure this is the whole disk and not a subset? Use `lvdisplay` to figure out what is behind this device name.

Comment: `/dev/Storage/Storage` is an LV under LVM. Containing what's left of a mangled ext4 filesystem I'm currently working on recovering. I'll take the advice about bs on my second go round. I think I know why it errored the first time but I was hoping it finished. Thanks for pointing out the obvious which I clearly didn't see with the running two `dd` commands haha. Would I tell both `dd` commands to use that bs or only the one reading the disk?

Comment: Nvm...holy balls...1M bs for da win.

Answer (score 5):

Look in your kernel log messages (`dmesg`, or `/var/log/kern.log`) for more detailed messages from the SATA drivers, if it was a hardware error.  Also useful: `smartctl -x /dev/sda`.  If it was just an attempt to read past the end of a partition or something, that might also show up in the kernel log.

To get dd to keep going after an i/o error, to read the readable parts that follow the error, use

```
dd if=... of=... conv=noerror bs=128k   # it doesn't get any faster beyond about 128k, because of L2 cache size
```

(As mentioned in comments on the OP, `ddrescue` has this and more.  `conv=noerror` was added to GNU dd after `ddrescue` existed, IIRC.)

If you want to resume where you left off, you can use the `seek` and `skip` options, with `conv=notrunc`.

---

If you really want to see how far along dd is, look at the file position of its stdin:

```
cat /proc/$(pidof dd)/fdinfo/0  # dd opens its infile as fd #0
```

(or `ls -lh` the size of the output file).  Copying a whole hard-drive worth of data 2 extra times by piping it through something seems silly to me, like it will just make your computer a tiny bit slower than needed for the hours the copy will take.

Or at least do:

```
dd if=... conv=noerror bs=128k | pv > Storage.img
```

Comment: Note that you can `kill -USR1 ` the process PID to get the `dd` stats.

Comment: You can also use the `progress` command (https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) which does automatically the same thing as the `fdinfo`-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and none of the tutorials or SO posts regarding `dd` specifically were helping out my particular form of this issue. After some digging, I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253117/how-do-i-fix-an-input-output-error-using-dd). [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/253119/306972) really worked well for me.

Here is an example for your use case:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gddrescue

$ sudo ddrescue /dev/Storage/Storage Storage.img | pv
```

The general form is:

```
$ sudo ddrescue <in_file> <out_file>
```

and then of course `| pv` if you want to pipe the `stdout` to the progress monitoring tool.