# mplayer audio capture

Tags: linux, mplayer, audio-cd

I have an ancient audio CD that I'd like to play.  So far nothing will touch it except mplayer, it seems the disk is defective but mplayer soldiers through.  I can't copy the disk either nor rip the audio off -- everything hangs.  So, I'm wondering if there is some software that specifically handles CD errors, or if I can get mplayer to dump the audio to a file.

Comment: this may give you some clue
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223514/84561

Comment: I'm trying ddrescue right now.  If the error remains then hafta find some thing  that, like mplayer, will skip the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 mplayer -ao pcm:file=/aMisc/ManInTheRhine.wav -cdrom-device /dev/sr0 cdda:// -cache 500000
```

I had to buffer the entire song to cope with the low quality of the CD but the result is perfect.  Only mplayer could read it.